# For people on earth, is it possible to harvest energy by decelerating the planet rotation?

Tags: science-based, astronomy

I was working on a side project to design an alien fleet that is wandering in the universe, and harvesting energy from planets for their needs. While I can think of ways to make that happen (geothermal, coal/fossil, "alien technology"), I was actually wondering if it is possible for people on earth to do similar things.

Specifically, I wonder if it is possible for people on earth, with modern technology (21st century), to utilize the kinetic energy from earth by decelerating the rotation?

Utilize here not just mean to help with launching rockets, but more referring to a machine/mechanism that can decelerate the planet rotation, and gain electricity/thermal energy from this process.

If it is not feasible right now, what would be a plan to make that happen, if the technology level is not a hard constrain? Lower technological level is more preferred.

Comment: Before harvesting energy by _decelerating_ a planet, you would better ask how we can harvest energy of an already spinning planet.

Comment: @kikirex I thought these two are the same thing, as I can't think of a way that we gain energy while the planet preserve it's spin speed.

Comment: So....no easy, cheap solar power for these fiends? They really, really need to mess with our calendars? May the owls deafen them with their incessant hooting.

Comment: @user535733 well these alien bastards love to mess around!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, it is possible and people do it.  [Tidal turbines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_stream_generator) generate power off of the tide rising and falling.  This is indirectly generating power off of the Earth's rotation, and here is a diagram explaining why.[image]

The earth has such a massive amount of kinetic energy that tapping into it a little is not noticed, but building thousands of tidal turbines would seriously start to convert the kinetic energy of the earth into electricity.

Comment: This is generating energy from both the Earth's rotation and the moon's orbit, it's similar to natural [tidal friction](https://www.britannica.com/science/tidal-friction) which converts some rotational energy to heat, also causing the moon's orbital radius to increase, so the decreasing angular momentum due to the Earth's rotation slowing is compensated for by the increased ang. momentum of the moon. Due to conservation of ang. momentum, it shouldn't be possible to directly convert energy from rotation to some other form like electricity without increasing ang. momentum of some other system.

Comment: The external torque is the movement of water back and forth on the face of the earth.  Since the water is "sloshing" back and forth, it is possible to tether it with a turbine, slowing the earth and generating electricity.

Comment: But this sloshing only happens because there is an external torque from the moon on the combined system consisting of both the water and the non-water portions of the Earth. The total angular momentum of the Earth-moon system can be treated as constant (I assume tidal friction from the Sun and other planets is negligible), so If the angular momentum of the non-water portion of the Earth is decreasing over millions of yrs, it's not being compensated for by an increase in the angular momentum of the oceans as a whole, it's just being compensated for by increased angular momentum of the moon.

Comment: The gravity of the moon is creating torque on the oceans, and the turbines are applying the torque in the oceans against the earth's rotation and generating electricity.

Comment: That way of explaining it sounds basically right to me, although the [explanation for the sloshing](https://mrgris.com/blog/2013-12-28-fucking-tides-how-do-they-work/) is apparently a little more complicated than the explanation for the overall tidal bulge. But do you agree with my comment that this method "is generating energy from both the Earth's rotation and the moon's orbit", along with my point that any process that's converting some of the kinetic energy from the Earth's rotation to electricity must involve a balancing increase of angular momentum of some other entity like the moon?

Comment: Yes.  Without the gravity of the moon, it would be impossible.

Comment: @BilboBaggins: There a solar component in the tides, about one third of that due to the moon. So there would be tides even without the moon, albeit smaller.

Comment: I didn't know that.  I looked it up on Wikipedia, and it's true, though.

Comment: I dig this idea. One caveat about this is that even without the rotation of earth, this plan still works, so it's more like extracting energy from the moon orbiting (in which case I'd assume the moon is accelerating the earth). I believe however, the solar component is from the earth rotation.

Comment: @Chenxi GE - There would be no tidal friction with the Sun (and therefore no energy to extract from tides) if the Earth were tidally locked with the Sun, i.e. if it rotated once a year so the same point on its surface was always facing the Sun. On the other hand, if the Earth weren't rotating at all (as seen by an inertial observer at rest relative to the Sun, say), there *would* be tidal friction from the Sun, because the tidal bulge would be moving relative to geographic locations on the Earth's surface. So this is another case where you can extract energy with no rotation.

Comment: @BilboBaggins Don't use that tidal bulge diagram. It's misleading, see this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121858/232868

Comment: The diagram not being 100% correct does not have an effect on the concept of the turbines.  I really don't think it matters that much.

Answer (score 6):

Doable, yes. Feasible, no. This shouldn't surprise you, because if it was feasible, presumably Elon Musk would have done it.

This sounds really weird, but as it happens, there's a way to gain *kinetic* energy, which can then presumably be transferred to thermal/electric energy, which functions as a result of using the Earth's movement and slows it down. And the good news is that its possible with today's technology. It's referred to as the [Gravity Assist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist). (Technically, it doesn't actually slow down the Earth's rotation, it slows down the Earth's orbit around the Sun. Fine. But it's a far better system because it takes more energy to rotate the Earth around the Sun than to spin the Earth, so more energy is gained.)

It has some downsides, namely the incredibly large energy expenditure needed to be able to get a ship into position to use the gravity assist, and that the alignment needs to be right, and that you'll accelerate the ship to a vector you don't necessarily want. But if you somehow managed to set up the system, you can use the Earth's movement for energy.

Answer (score 4):

This is both doable and feasible, even with near-future technology.

As described in David Brin's short story ["Tank Farm Dynamo"](http://www.davidbrin.com/tankfarm.htm) (1983), you can let an orbiting satellite have a large wire loop that interacts with the Earth's magnetic field to produce electricity. This slows down the satellite, making its orbit decline, but it will also slow down the Earth's rotation a tiny, tiny fraction.

A much Larger version of this would be to wrap a wire spool all the way around the Moon, generating electricity as the Moon travels through the Earth's magnetic field, slowing both the Moon's orbit and the Earth's rotation in the process.

What I can't tell is if the energy generated would be of a magnitude to justify the expense, compared to mining Helium 3 and using it for fusion power.

Comment: Compared to mining Helium 3 from the Moon? Probably. Compared to mining Helium 3 from a source that would actually makes sense like Saturn, or (even better) breeding it? Harder to say.

Comment: @Eth: I mentioned the Moon since that was where I put the spool.

Comment: Or even building an insanely tall wind power station on moon. The wind power station is so tall that it reaches the earth (dense) atmosphere and generates electricity. More unrealistic than your design though.

Answer (score 2):

In 1992 there was a US patent issued for the "Earth Gyro Transducer" which sought to convert the earth's rotation into usable energy with an anchored gyroscope.  I've never seen any information on anyone who's actually constructed it.  US Patent #:5,313,850.

> This specification describes a completely new and different concept... namely:
> the use of a gyroscope to generate output power from the earth's
> stored inertial rotational (flywheel) energy by fixing the housing of
> the gyroscope to the earth and using the rotation of the earth
> relative to the gyroscope's spatially stable rotor/gimbal assembly to
> rotate the input shaft(s) of a power transducer(s).
> https://patents.google.com/patent/US5313850A/en

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  I hope you don't mind my adding a link and some of the text. It's usual on SE to substantiate answers by quoting in this way.

Comment: So, is there a flaw in the underlying reasoning of this patent, or is it only impractical?

Answer (score 0):

Technically we already do this with wind power. Wind power means accelerating wind turbines by slowing down wind. By the action-reaction law, this slowing down of the wind also slows down Earth - a tiny bit. I'm not qualified to calculate by how much, but to get a sense of the proportions, here are the masses involved (according to Google):

- Earth: 5,972 × 10^24 kg
- Atmosphere: 5 × 10^15 kg